# How to run external scripts from django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do basic keyword tool with django and so far I set up tables and CVS import option. Now I would like to use external google scraper script (https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) to analyse these keywords once they are added to django's ORM(google each keyword and save top10 results for latter analyses).

Running this script outside of django is easy:

```
import sys
from GoogleScraper import scrape_with_config, GoogleSearchError
from GoogleScraper.database import ScraperSearch, SERP, Link

# very basic usage
def basic_usage():
    # See in the config.cfg file for possible values
    config = {
        'SCRAPING': {
...
if __name__ == '__main__':

usage = 'Usage: {} [basic|image]'.format(sys.argv[0])
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(usage)
else:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
    if arg == 'basic':
...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Is this the best way to go about it ?

Are there maybe some examples of similar scripts being implemented in Django that I could see and learn :) ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the script in your app directory then you can import in the view

```
from GoogleScraper import basic_usage

def view_fun(request):
    basic_usage()
    return Response
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for :)